# Routing with VPN [Windows]

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, openvpn

I'm connected via WiFi to the network of my university. I need to connect to a VPN in order to get internet access. In addition I want to connect to my home network, so I can access my network drives. I'm using OpenVPN to connect to both VPNs.

```
WiFi:
  IP: 192.168.47.201
  MASK: 255.255.252.0
  Default Gateway: 192.168.44.1

University VPN:
  IP: 134.108.57.83
  GW: 134.108.57.1

Home VPN
  IP: 10.8.0.10
  GW: 10.8.0.9
```

My network drive has the IP 192.168.10.26. I thought I just need to add a route with `route add 192.168.10.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.9`, however I'm unable to access the drive or any device in my home network. Which routes do I have to add in order to get this working?

`route print:`

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...30 65 ec 9f 09 04 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  8...ca ff 28 29 4d dd ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  3...00 ff 2e af 66 ba ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 10...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 16...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  4...00 ff 35 f9 0a 0d ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9 #2
  6...c8 ff 28 29 4d dd ......Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless Network Adapter
  2...c8 ff 28 29 4d de ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.44.1   192.168.47.201     35
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     134.108.57.1    134.108.57.83     36
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6     35
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6     35
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.252         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.6  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.7  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
         10.8.0.9  255.255.255.255     134.108.57.1    134.108.57.83     36
    62.158.129.58  255.255.255.255     192.168.44.1   192.168.47.201     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0     134.108.57.1    134.108.57.83     36
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.5         10.8.0.6     35
     134.108.57.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     134.108.57.83    291
    134.108.57.83  255.255.255.255         On-link     134.108.57.83    291
   134.108.57.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     134.108.57.83    291
     192.168.10.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.9    134.108.57.83     36
     192.168.11.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.11.1    291
     192.168.11.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.11.1    291
   192.168.11.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.11.1    291
     192.168.35.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
     192.168.35.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
   192.168.35.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
     192.168.44.0    255.255.252.0         On-link    192.168.47.201    291
   192.168.47.201  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.47.201    291
   192.168.47.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.47.201    291
   193.197.62.100  255.255.255.255     192.168.44.1   192.168.47.201     36
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.47.201    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.11.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     134.108.57.83    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.47.201    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.35.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.11.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.6    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     134.108.57.83    291
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Your home computers also need to know how to respond. They need a route to your VPN. Can you add custom routes in your router?

Comment: Yes I think so. But do I really need this? I connect to the home VPN, which bridges the connection to my home network. The strange thing is, I managed to get it work somehow. Only with routes on my laptop. But that was a few days ago I have no clue what I did back then

Comment: Although it may sometimes appear that way, regular routing doesn’t know about relations between packets. So your NAS or whatever tries to respond but the response won’t go into the VPN but instead to your router. // I forgot to ask, who’s connecting to the VPN? Your router? Or a PC?

Comment: With my Laptop I'm connecting to the OpenVPN Server hosted on my NAS which gives me an IP in the subnet 10.8.0.0/24. In the Server config (it's an integrated feature to the NAS) there's an option checked called "Redirect Gateway". Not sure if this is any helpful information. Which static routes do I need in my Router? Do I need to make a route so all packets to 10.8.0.0/24 go to the NAS (IP 192.168.10.26)?

Comment: So, just to clarify: Your NAS is the VPN server and you want to access the NAS (and nothing else) over VPN?